# Dynamic variables from dataframe value in R with value names?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a dataframe of types and values like so:

| topic | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| cheese | cheddar |
| meat | beef |
| meat | chicken |
| cheese | swiss |
| bread | focaccia |
| bread | sourdough |
| cheese | gouda |

My aim is to make a set of dynamic regexs based on the type, but I don't know how to make the variable names from the types. I can do this individually like so:

```
fn_get_topic_regex <- function(targettopic,df)
{
  filter_df <- df |>
    filter(topic == targettopic)
  regex <- paste(filter_df$keyword, collapse =  "|")
}
```

and do things like:

`cheese_regex <- fn_get_topic_regex("cheese",df)`

But what I'd like to be able to do is build all these regexes automatically without having to define each one.

The intended output would be something like:

```
cheese_regex: "cheddar|swiss|gouda"
bread_regex: "focaccia|sourdough"
meat_regex: "beef|chicken"
```

Where the start of the variable name is the distinct topic.

What's the best way to do that without defining each regex individually by hand?

Comment: Function `assign()` may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`'s `group_by()` and `summarise()`

```
df %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  summarise(regex = paste(keyword, collapse = "|"))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  topic  regex              
  <chr>  <chr>              
1 bread  focaccia|sourdough 
2 cheese cheddar|swiss|gouda
3 meat   beef|chicken
```

Or you can apply your function to every unique value in `df$topic`:

```
map_chr(unique(df$topic) %>% setNames(paste0(., "_regex")),
        fn_get_topic_regex, df = df)

         cheese_regex            meat_regex           bread_regex 
"cheddar|swiss|gouda"        "beef|chicken"  "focaccia|sourdough"
```

Just remember to add `return(regex)` to the end of your function, or not to assign the last line to a variable at all. I would even put everything in a single pipe chain:

```
fn_get_topic_regex <- function(targettopic,df)
{
  df |>
    filter(topic == targettopic) |>
    pull(keyword) |>
    paste(collapse =  "|")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution with your intended output in a named list.

```
df <- structure(list(topic = c("cheese", "meat", "meat", "cheese", "bread", "bread", "cheese"), 
                     keyword = c("cheddar", "beef", "chicken", "swiss", "focaccia", "sourdough", "gouda")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

#split into a list per topic
topics <- split(df, df$topic)

#collapse the keyword column
topics <- lapply(topics, function(t) {
   paste(t$keyword, collapse =  "|")
})

#rename
names(topics)<- paste0(names(topics), "_regex")

topics

$bread_regex
[1] "focaccia|sourdough"

$cheese_regex
[1] "cheddar|swiss|gouda"

$meat_regex
[1] "beef|chicken"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do something like this:

1. after grouping we could use `summarise` together with `paste` and `collapse` to get our regex s
2. Then, when the regex is needed we could refer to it by indexing like the example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) #str_detect
my_regex <- df %>% 
  group_by(topic) %>% 
  summarise(regex = paste(keyword, collapse = "|"))

df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(str_detect(keyword, my_regex$regex[1]), "it is bread", "it is not bread"))
```

```
 A tibble: 3 × 2
  topic  regex              
  <chr>  <chr>              
1 bread  focaccia|sourdough 
2 cheese cheddar|swiss|gouda
3 meat   beef|chicken       
> df %>% 
+   mutate(new_col = ifelse(str_detect(keyword, my_regex$regex[1]), "it is bread", "it is not bread"))
   topic   keyword         new_col
1 cheese   cheddar it is not bread
2   meat      beef it is not bread
3   meat   chicken it is not bread
4 cheese     swiss it is not bread
5  bread  focaccia     it is bread
6  bread sourdough     it is bread
7 cheese     gouda it is not bread
```